# after json decode merge

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

after json decode array merge

```php
$permission_roles1 = DB::table('permission_roles')->select('permission_name')->first();
$permission_roles2 = DB::table('user_permissions')->select('userP_name')->first();

$json_array1 = json_decode($permission_roles1->permission_name);
$json_array2 = json_decode($permission_roles2->userP_name);
$arr1 = array($json_array1);
$arr2= array($json_array2);

$res = array_merge($arr1, $arr2); 
dd($res);
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

In your code,

```
$json_array1 = json_decode($permission_roles1->permission_name);
$json_array2 = json_decode($permission_roles2->userP_name);
```

returns object not an array.

Just changed  it to

```
$json_array1 = json_decode($permission_roles1->permission_name, true);
$json_array2 = json_decode($permission_roles2->userP_name, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

convert array object into array then merge the array

```
$permission_roles1 = DB::table('permission_roles')->select('permission_name')->first();
$permission_roles2 = DB::table('user_permissions')->select('userP_name')->first();

 $arr1 = (array) $permission_roles1->permission_name;
 $arr2 = (array) $permission_roles2->userP_name;

$res = array_merge($arr1, $arr2); 

dd($res);
```